# How do I build and run my first helloworld application in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I just installed VS CODE on my machine, created new file helloworld.cs. 
**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
public class Hello
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Pressing **F5** (in order to select the environment) I select VSCODE Extension Environment. Then the ***launch.json*** file appears whose code is shown below:

```
    {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/out",
            "preLaunchTask": "npm"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now that I saved the launch.json 
 I get the error:

```
Info : No task runner configured.
```

I selected dotnet core as task runner then the **tasks.json** file pops up :

```
  {
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "npm",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "install",
            "args": ["install"]
        },
        {
            "taskName": "update",
            "args": ["update"]
        },
        {
            "taskName": "test",
            "args": ["run", "test"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Finally I compile the helloworld.cs and again the error pops up as:

```
Error: Could not find tha preLaunchTask 'npm'.
```

I'm just lost in the vicious circle. I drilled down through the [basics from Visual Studio site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/basics), yet I have no clue about what I'm doing. Is there any easily understandable wiki, blogs which could help me out.

Comment: Do you npm installed?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/dotnet